# MySQL scheduled event doesn't work on replica instance once it becomes master during failover

Tags: mysql, triggers, innodb, replication

Given MySQL InnoDB 8 cluster with router, master and two replicas.

1. There is trigger for table_1 to copy data to table_2 every time data inserted to table_1.
2. There is scheduled event that creates daily partitions on table_3.

By design trigger and scheduled event enabled only for source (current master) instance and disabled in replicas.

Once master goes down, and one of replicas become master the trigger and scheduled event doesn't work without manually enabling them. What are workarounds and practices to cause it work automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Following documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-invoked.html

> When promoting a replica having such events to a source, you must
> enable each event using ALTER EVENT event_name ENABLE, where
> event_name is the name of the event.

Seems like MySQL server doesn't support this functionality automatically. External job scheduler should be used to trigger stored procedures.